# Plugin com.intellij failed to initialize and will be disabled: null

Tags: android, android-studio

I followed the documentation about android-studio, however, when i execute the studio.sh i got this error:

Plugin com.intellij failed to initialize and will be disabled: null

Answer (score 8):

This is because of jdk installation location fixed in an [IntelliJ IDEA class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/12.0/com/intellij/openapi/projectRoots/impl/JavaSdkImpl.java#156).

When you install the jdk (sun or openJDK) from the repository, it installs in any of the following locations:

- `/usr/java` or
- `/opt/java` or
- `/usr/lib/jvm`

So if you have installed it manually by getting the tar and extracting it to some location other than above, you need to move your jdk folder content to any of the above locations.

Comment: AmitChotaliya 's answer work for me, I unzip sun jdk to /usr/local/jdk, just ln -sv /usr/local/jdk /opt/java make all things work

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your computer **`JAVA_HOME`** is configured correctly

Comment: JAVA_HOME should reference the latest jdk not jre

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie, what OS have you tried to launch on? I've tried on Ubuntu 12.04 x64. I added `export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_45/` to my `.profile` and the error dialog keeps showing up.

Comment: I followed AmitChotaliya's advice and launched Android Studio. The `JAVA_HOME` variable wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try OpenJDK instead of Sun Jdk.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change to openjdk, it solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well updating the jdk helped me .

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a 64 bit system on opensuse the jvm is installed in /usr/lib64/jvm

I had to cd into /usr/lib and symlink /usr/lib64/jvm

```
cd /usr/lib && sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/jvm
```